# Query in getting value of second attribute after giving value of first attribute inside array in Mongo db

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, filter, attributes

I am a newbie in Mongo .

I have a requirement to build a query from a complex document inside a collection.

```
{ "_id" : "http://nsgfds.com",
        "has Title" : [
                {
                        "title" : {
                                "language" : "eng",
                                "value" : "eng title"
                        },
                        "origin" : "https://Ignore",
                        "score" : 7.5
                },
                {
                        "title" : {
                                "language" : "chi",
                                "value" : "Chinese title"
                        },
                        "origin" : "https://Ignore",
                        "score" : 7.5
                },
                {
                        "title" : {
                                "language" : "vie",
                                "value" : "Vietnamese title"
                        },
                        "origin" : "https://Ignore",
                        "score" : 7.5
                },
                {
                        "title" : {
                                "language" : "asm",
                                "value" : "Assamese title"
                        },
                        "origin" : "https://Ignore",
                        "score" : 7.5
                }
        ]
}
```

My query wants to return value of "value" field when "language" and "_id" values given

suppose when I give "_id" and "language" the query should return only value of the "value" field based on "_id" and "language".
My query:

```
db.collectionname.aggregate([
  {$match: {"_id": "http://nsgfds.com"}},
  {  
    $project: {
      hasTitle: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$hasTitle", 
          as:"item", 
          cond: { $eq: ["$title.language:eng", "$$item.value"]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
]).pretty();
```

Expected output:

```
{
"_id" : "http://nsgfds.com",
"hasTitle" : [{"title" : {"value" : "Wiley Title English title"}]
};
```

Actual Output:

```
{
        "_id" : "http://nsgfds.com",
        "hasTitle" : [
                {
                        "title" : {
                                "language" : "eng",
                                "value" : "Wiley Title English title"
                        },
                        "origin" : "https://Ignore",
                        "score" : 7.5
                },
                {
                        "title" : {
                                "language" : "chi",
                                "value" : "chinese title"
                        },
                        "origin" : "https://Ignore",
                        "score" : 7.5
                },
                {
                        "title" : {
                                "language" : "vie",
                                "value" : "Vietnamese title"
                        },
                        "origin" : "https://Ignore",
                        "score" : 7.5
                },
                {
                        "title" : {
                                "language" : "asm",
                                "value" : "Assamese title"
                        },
                        "origin" : "https://Ignore",
                        "score" : 7.5
                }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from your condition, where you should compare an element of the list (`$$item`) with a string (eng, asm, shi ...)

```
{
    $eq: [
        "$$item.title.language",
        "eng"
    ]
}
```

But this will give you :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "http://nsgfds.com",
    "hasTitle": [
      {
        "origin": "https://Ignore",
        "score": 7.5,
        "title": {
          "language": "eng",
          "value": "eng title"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

To get your desired output, you will need another `$project`

```
{
    $project: {
        "hasTitle.title.value": "$hasTitle.title.value"
    }
}
```

result :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "http://nsgfds.com",
    "hasTitle": [
      {
        "title": {
          "value": [
            "eng title"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```